# How to solve error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT 
    A.SETMOD, B.DESCRP 
FROM 
    PMS.PSBSTTBL A 
JOIN 
    PMS.PR029TBL B ON A.SETMOD = B.PAYMOD
```

`Paymod` is of datatype `VARCHAR`, `SETMOD` of type `decimal`

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: THANKS MARC. I WANT TO CONVERT THE DATA TYPE  IN THIS QUERY IT'S SELF

Comment: Is varchar columsn compatiable with decimal?

Comment: Please ***STOP*** writing in ALL UPPERCASE ! It's annoying, it's hard to read - and worst of all, it's considered ***SHOUTING*** at people which is just plain rude and offensive. Please don't keep on doing that!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing is to convert the decimal to string and compare it with the string value.. make necessary adjustments on the decimal part.. :)

```
SELECT 
    A.SETMOD, B.DESCRP 
FROM 
    PMS.PSBSTTBL A 
JOIN 
    PMS.PR029TBL B ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),A.SETMOD) = B.PAYMOD
```

Answer (score 1):

A `join` to two columns of different types is a really, really bad idea.  Sometimes, though, other people design database systems, and we don't have a choice.

You have two choices, basically:  convert both to numbers or both to strings.  You are getting the error because in mixed type expressions, SQL Server converts to the more "restrictive" type (to simplify the logic).  So, it converts the string to a number.

In SQL Server 2012+, I would suggest `try_convert()` for the conversion to a number:

```
SELECT A.SETMOD, B.DESCRP 
FROM PMS.PSBSTTBL A JOIN 
     PMS.PR029TBL B
     ON A.SETMOD = TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(?, ?), B.PAYMOD);
```

The `?,?` should be the scale/precision of `SETMOD`.

Of course, you could also force the conversion in the other direction:

```
SELECT A.SETMOD, B.DESCRP 
FROM PMS.PSBSTTBL A JOIN 
     PMS.PR029TBL B
     ON CAST(A.SETMOD AS VARCHAR(255)) = B.PAYMOD;
```

This conversion will succeed, so you don't need `TRY_CONVERT()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
A.SETMOD, B.DESCRP 
FROM 
PMS.PSBSTTBL A 
JOIN 
PMS.PR029TBL B ON A.SETMOD =convert(decimal, B.PAYMOD)
```